# Custom bottom sheet container using SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, scrollview, swiftui-list, swiftui-sheet

I'm trying to create a custom expandable view, something like on gif below:

[image]

I'm trying to use offsets for a container, but there is a problem with content, when the content is scrollable (like ScrollView or List etc) as every scrollable catches drag events and handle them internally.

Is any way to scroll parent container when child scrollable view riches its edge corner?
I saw, how native bottom sheet works in SwiftUI. This behaviour of scroll is pretty much like I need but I cannot use `sheet()` modifier because it expands not in scope of UI but like separate screen.

Comment: What do you mean by "I cannot use sheet() modifier because it expands not in scope of UI but like separate screen"? Your gif looks exactly like a sheet to me.

Comment: @Sweeper, native sheet() modifier in expand state looks like this:
https://teletype.in/files/86/35/86354351-a8d8-4467-874f-5bf23847168f.png

Comment: Are you aware of [`presentationDetents`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/presentationdetents(_:))?

Comment: @Sweeper, Thanks for an idea with 'presentationDetents' It is preeety much what I need.
One small detail - is it possible to allow clicks under bottom sheet? I will send a screenshot: https://prnt.sc/y8DhTo-ZqI9s
Here on top of bottom sheet I have swipeable calendar. I need to interact with it, when the bottomsheet is open

Comment: [`presentationBackgroundInteraction`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/presentationbackgroundinteraction(_:))?

Comment: @Sweeper, thanks a lot for help! I've been researching for a week. Tried many custom solutions but it is solved natively 

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.sheet()` with `presentationDetents` as shown in the example below. The sheet height adjusts according to the content, when the content of the bottom sheet reaches up to 80% of the screen, it will start scrolling. You can also interact with the content behind and above the sheet, as demonstrated in this example with open and close buttons, hope this solves your query.

[image: ScreenShot]

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var isSheetOpen = true
    @State private var bottomSheetHeight: CGFloat = 0
    private var maxHeightBottomSheet = (UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.8)
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            
            Button(action: {
                isSheetOpen = true
            } ) {
                Text("Open Sheet")
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
            }
            .frame(height: 50)
            .background(Color.white)
            .padding(.horizontal, 50)
            .padding(.top, 100)
            
            Button(action: {
                isSheetOpen = false
            } ) {
                Text("Close Sheet")
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
            }
            .frame(height: 50)
            .background(Color.white)
            .padding(.horizontal, 50)
            
            Spacer()
        }
        .background(Color.blue.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all))
        
        .sheet(isPresented: $isSheetOpen, content: {
            BottomSheet(height: $bottomSheetHeight)
                .presentationDetents([.height(min(bottomSheetHeight, maxHeightBottomSheet))])
                .shadow(color: .black, radius: 5)
        })
        .ignoresSafeArea(.all)
    }
}


struct BottomSheet: View {
    
    @Binding var height: CGFloat
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ScrollView {
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                
                // Handle bar
                Rectangle()
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 6)
                    .cornerRadius(3.0)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                    .padding(.top, 10)
                
                Rectangle()
                    .frame(height:  100)
                    .foregroundColor(.clear)
                Text("Drag down to close sheet")
                Text("BottomSheet")
                
                Rectangle()
                    .frame(height:  250)
                    .foregroundColor(.clear)
            }
            .background(.green)
            .readSize { calculatedHeight in
                height = calculatedHeight.height
            }
        }
    }
}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}


extension View {
    func readSize(onChange: @escaping (CGSize) -> Void) -> some View {
        background(
            GeometryReader { geometryProxy in
                Color.clear
                    .preference(key: SizePreferenceKey.self, value: geometryProxy.size)
            }
        )
        .onPreferenceChange(SizePreferenceKey.self, perform: onChange)
    }
}

struct SizePreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: CGSize = .zero
    static func reduce(value: inout CGSize, nextValue: () -> CGSize) {}
}
```

Comment: Hello @Jayant. Actually I already used regular `sheet`. But I have some problems with it as I'm using this sheet inside one of screens in bottom nav bar (I have 3 tabs, one of them has this `sheet`). And when I'm clicking to other tabs, the `sheet` is still visible. Also the problem is that the `sheet` still visible when user navigates to next screen from one of tabs (problem like in prev case, when sheet visible on other tab). For now I don't know how to fix it, expects creating new Window instance on top of my current and preview all next navigation in it.

Comment: @SergeyGrishin, simply set `isSheetOpen` to false whenever the user clicks on any other tabs. Alternatively, you can set `bottomSheetHeight` to 0.

Comment: I tried this way, but it closes with animation, what is looks not good